# How do I assign values from a dataframe to deciles created in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment, finance

I am working with two dataframes:

- `df` contains a column `be/me` for stocks for a 20-year period (on a monthly basis).
- `df2`, a subset of `df` (with only certain stocks, only for June) contains the column `decile`, created via the `pd.qcut()` method for every year in the 20-year period based on an altered version of `df`'s `be/me`.

Considering the deciles that I created in `df2`, I wonder if it's possible to rank `df`'s `be/me` based on `df2`'s `decile` column. In other words, I wonder if it's possible to assign `df`'s `be/me` values to the deciles created in `df2`.

Please see dataframes below for a better understanding of the issue:

```
             
df

date         stock_id      be/me    
2000-01-31    1004.0        0.3      
2000-02-29    1004.0        0.7 
2000-03-31    1004.0        1.2 
2000-04-30    1004.0        2.3 
2000-05-31    1004.0        0.9 
...            ...          ...
2020-12-31    3900.0        1.7
2020-12-31    3900.0        2.8
2020-12-31    3900.0        3.0
2020-12-31    3900.0        0.2
2020-12-31    3900.0        2.1

1218855 rows × 3 columns


df2['deciles'] = df2.groupby('date')['be/me'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, labels=False, duplicates = 'drop'))
df2

date        stock_id      be/me  deciles                    
2000-06-30  2061.0      0.653684    5
2000-06-30  4383.0      0.053660    2
2000-06-30  13561.0     0.092509    2
2000-06-30  4065.0      1.342187    6
2000-06-30  2731.0      0.235582    3
  ...         ...          ...     ...
2020-06-30  7022.0      0.072534    2
2020-06-30  30990.0     1.071096    6
2020-06-30  22867.0     1.627155    6
2020-06-30  15247.0     0.051387    2
2020-06-30  61574.0     1.684690    6

24095 rows × 4 columns
```

Note: `date` is of type `datetime` and, for each date, there are multiple stocks (`stock_id`).
Thank you so much for your time.

## **EDIT**

What I want to do is to check in which `df2`-created decile the original `be/me` values (from the original dataframe `df`) fit. The expected output should be a new column in `df` with `df2`-created deciles attributed to each and every `be/me` value in `df`.
Please let me know if there is any additional clarification necessary.

I created a function that loops through the deciles to fetch the maximum decile value for every `date` in `df2`. Not sure if I am heading in the right direction since the output is an array with no `date`... take a look below:

```
In: def attribution(deciles,dates):
    deciles = df2['deciles'].unique()
    dates = df2.index.unique()
    body_max = []
    body_min = []
    for x in deciles:
        for y in dates:
            body_max.append(df2[df2['deciles'] == x].loc[y]['be/me'].max())
            body_min.append(df2[df2['deciles'] == x].loc[y]['be/me'].min())
            
    return body_max, body_min

In: attribution(deciles, dates)
Out: [0.9343106070197438,
 1.2747264875802489,
 1.9700461181925901,
 0.7888946814157697,
 0.9304702071896337,
 0.9651423313922733,
 0.7238677612487585,
 1.0358317574924074,
 ...]
```

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Please see edit above, @user17242583. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: you want to know for each `be/me` value in `df` which decile it would have fallen into if that value had been in `df2`? I see two cases:

1. If `df2` covers the whole month of June (as you wrote), I am afraid there is no answer to that question: each day in the month will have decile bins with different edges (since you are doing a `groupby('date')` on `df2`). The same `be/me` value in `df` could belong to different deciles in `df2` depending on the day in June you consider.
2. If `df2` actually covers only one day in June (as your example above seems to indicate: `2020-06-30`), then you have one well defined set of decile bins.

In case 2), you could do that:

```
df
        date  stock_od  be/me
0 2000-01-31    1004.0    0.3
1 2000-02-29    1004.0    0.7
2 2000-03-31    1004.0    1.2
3 2000-04-30    1004.0    2.3
4 2000-05-31    1004.0    0.9
5 2020-12-31    3900.0    1.7
6 2020-12-31    3900.0    2.8
7 2020-12-31    3900.0    3.0
8 2020-12-31    3900.0    0.2
9 2020-12-31    3900.0    2.1

df2
        date  stock_id     be/me
0 2000-06-30    2061.0  0.653684
1 2000-06-30    4383.0  0.053660
2 2000-06-30   13561.0  0.092509
3 2000-06-30    4065.0  1.342187
4 2000-06-30    2731.0  0.235582
5 2000-06-30    7022.0  0.072534
6 2000-06-30   30990.0  1.071096
7 2000-06-30   22867.0  1.627155
8 2000-06-30   15247.0  0.051387
9 2000-06-30   61574.0  1.684690

deciles = pd.qcut(df2['be/me'], 10, labels=False, duplicates = 'drop', retbins=True)

deciles
(0    5
 1    1
 2    3
 3    7
 4    4
 5    2
 6    6
 7    8
 8    0
 9    9
 Name: be/me, dtype: int64,
 array([0.051387 , 0.0534327, 0.0687592, 0.0865165, 0.1783528, 0.444633 ,
        0.8206488, 1.1524233, 1.3991806, 1.6329085, 1.68469  ]))

df.loc[:,'deciles'] = np.digitize(df['be/me'],deciles[1])-1

df
        date  stock_od  be/me  deciles
0 2000-01-31    1004.0    0.3        4
1 2000-02-29    1004.0    0.7        5
2 2000-03-31    1004.0    1.2        7
3 2000-04-30    1004.0    2.3       10
4 2000-05-31    1004.0    0.9        6
5 2020-12-31    3900.0    1.7       10
6 2020-12-31    3900.0    2.8       10
7 2020-12-31    3900.0    3.0       10
8 2020-12-31    3900.0    0.2        4
9 2020-12-31    3900.0    2.1       10
```

With the argument `retbins=True` to `pd.qcut()` you get a tuple where the second item is an array containing the bin (here decile) edges.
You then apply the very handy numpy function `np.digitize()` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to the `df` column `be/me`, which gives you for each value which bin (decile) it belongs to.

**Note:** I added a `-1` because the numpy function `np.digitize()` returns the next decile compared to what `pd.qcut()` delivered. Probably because `np.digitize()` reserves deciles 0 and 10 for values that fall outside the lower and higher bin edges, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your (very detailed) answer! Case 2 was indeed the one I was referring to. Cheers!